# What is the name for a descriptive rising scale of quality

Tags: terminology

This is a difficult one, so here goes :
What is the name or technique used by companies to describe the quality or value of a product or service when grouped together. I.e Web hosting companies may have  bronze, Silver, Gold packages indicating a rising scale of quality. Paupers Meal, Princes Meal, Kings Meal.

Answer (score 2):

The term for the various levels, especially in a technology context, is usually `tiers` IE Gold Tier service.

The technique is called [Price Discrimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_discrimination), specifically `product versioning` or `vertical product versioning`

Also called `tiered pricing` or `menu pricing`.

Comment: Thanks Fodagus - i had a feeling tiered pricing was one of the phrases. Ive been using this technique for many years as a web developer but was never 100% sure what it was called. BTW ive upvoted you but as a newbie the creds aren't visible in the fron-end  - sorry - Thank Again.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer now, @FlimFlam. There is a delay of a few hours between posting a question and being able to accept an answer.